# how to get shared perference value in another activity

Tags: android, database, sharedpreferences

Have values in shared perference in activity1

like this

```
prefs=getSharedPreferences(prefName, MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor edtior=prefs.edit();
        edtior.putString(VALUE_KEY,check.toString());
        edtior.commit();
```

And i have need to get the value in another activity. i have tried like this

```
SharedPreferences prefs=getSharedPreferences(prefName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        edittext.setText(prefs.getString(VALUE_KEY,""));
```

This works fine.

Like this i need to get the same value in DBHelper class. How to get shared perferences value in DBHelper.

I have tried like this in DBHelper

```
SharedPreferences prefs=getSharedPreferences(prefName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            String key =(prefs.getString(VALUE_KEY,""));
```

What's wrong with Syntax?

Comment: i didn't get the perference value in DBHelper class.

Comment: please show `DBHelper class`code

Comment: check my edit code. it tells to create method

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SharedPreferences prefs= context.getSharedPreferences(prefName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String key =(prefs.getString(VALUE_KEY,""));
```

And you must have to pass `context` to DBHelper.

Answer (score 0):

For accessing `getSharedPreferences` method in DBHelper class you will need to pass Context using DBHelper class constructor as:

```
 private context;

 public DBHelper(Context context){
  this.context=context;
 }
```

Now use `context` to call `getSharedPreferences` method as:

```
SharedPreferences prefs=context.getSharedPreferences(prefName, 
                                               Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String key =(prefs.getString(VALUE_KEY,""));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It may be help you..

```
 SharedPreferences  _sPrefs =getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE); 
        String temp = _sPrefs.getString("VALUE_KEY", "");
```